# How can I stop the QR Code tracking on a HoloLens while maintaining the visualization its content?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, qr-code, hololens, openxr

I'm working on an application that scans a stationary QR code and creates a room around the user. This works fine. What I would like to do is scan the QR code, the room gets augmented, and then I stop tracking the QR code but keep the augmented room. It is necessary that the room is tied to the QR code in space, so I cannot just place it at random. I don't want to keep tracking the QR code either. I've tried multiple ways to stop the tracking, like calling StopTracking(), or removing the room model from the QR prefab once it's instantiated and reparenting it to the root of the hierarchy, or preventing the application from removing the QR code from its list or destroying the instantiated prefab. So far all this has accomplished is stopping the tracking as soon as the QR code is read, but then also gets rid of its visualized content.

I feel like there's a simple solution, but I have not been able to find it. I would really appreciate some suggestions/advice! This is all using Microsoft's Mixed Reality QR sample for OpenXR.

Comment: Could you please tell us how you detached the room model from the QR prefab and relocated it to the root? I think you are in the right direction, probably you need to remove more stuff manually, like the QR Code related components on the room model.

Comment: I made the room model a child of the QR Code prefab and then once the HoloLens recognized the code, I would look through the code's children for the room, and set the parent of the room to null, so it was at the root. There wasn't any QR code components on it since it was already a child of the code prefab to begin with. When I did this, and stopped tracking the QR Code, it shifted the room model around and flipped it upside down. I was hoping to avoid manually setting the position/rotation of the room model but that may be my only option.